# Excel conditional formatting - Highlight the cell in Calendar if the start date and end date is the same

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a question, is it possible to extend this formula: I have conditional formatting which highlight the cells in calendar based on the start date and end date where is there is text „Studio“.

Start date:
`=ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,(accomodation_2024!$F$7:$F$101="Studio")*(accomodation_2024!$G$7:$G$101=D5),0))`

End date:
`=ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,(accomodation_2024!$F$7:$F$101="Studio")*(accomodation_2024!$H$7:$H$101=D5),0))`

This formula basically firstly check whether in sheet accomodation_2024 is in column F text „Studio“ and than if yes than will highlight the start date in calendar based on column G and highlight the end date based on column H.

Is it possible to adjust this formula to find the same date (or overlapping date) in two columns F and H? It firstly need to also check for the „Studio“ condition. For example, I have start date in column G (08.01.2024) and end date in column H (08.01.2024).

Sometime the start date is the same as end date. The same precondition should applied if "accomodation_2024!$F$7:$F$101="Studio" than highlight cell where the start date is the same as end date. Thanks.

Edit: 31.01.2024 - added images of table, calendars and rules

Table accomodation_2024:
[image: table "accomodation_2024"]

calendars:
[image: calendars]

rules:
[image: Rules]

Comment: Could you post a sample table and/or an image showing some examples

Comment: Hi I have added the images of table "accomodation_2024" + image of calendars where I am trying to format the cells + image of rules applied so far. This basically highlight the start date and end date + dates in between + all other cells to red. The problem is the date 05.01.2024 which is appearing in both instances of studio as end date and start date. I would like to be able to format this overlapping date as separate colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=COUNTIFS(accomodation_2024!$F$2:$F$97,"Studio",accomodation_2024!$G$2:$G$97,D5)*COUNTIFS(accomodation_2024!$F$2:$F$97,"Studio",accomodation_2024!$H$2:$H$97,D5)
```

You can also use similar formulas for the other conditional formattings:

```
=COUNTIFS(accomodation_2024!$F$2:$F$97,"Studio",accomodation_2024!$H$2:$H$97,D5)
=COUNTIFS(accomodation_2024!$F$2:$F$97,"Studio",accomodation_2024!$G$2:$G$97,D5)
=COUNTIFS(accomodation_2024!$F$2:$F$97,"Studio",accomodation_2024!$G$2:$G$97,"<"&D5,accomodation_2024!$H$2:$H$97,">"&D5)
=COUNTIFS(accomodation_2024!$F$2:$F$97,"Studio",accomodation_2024!$G$2:$G$97,"<="&D5,accomodation_2024!$H$2:$H$97,">="&D5)=0
```

The last one especially since your red-coloring conditional formatting doesn't work as it should (it won't paint red the second week of jan 2024, for example).